# Mapping network drives

Tags: group-policy, window-server-2019

I'm trying to map a network drive using item level targeting based on a security group. When I map the drive based on security group it doesn't show up on client computers. If I map the drive based on a single user it works. Why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

It should work, as long as the GPO is a user setting not a computer one, the users are in or under the OU that the GPO has been placed in, the GPO permissions allow those users to see it and the users are not in an OU with disabled inheritance.

I am fairly sure it is a lot better for GPO processing speeds to use OU for your target though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the GPO got the deleguated right's "domain computer" at read.